# What is the best way to clear a session variable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

```
session[:message] = nil
```

Is this is the best way to destroy a session variable.

**Note:** I don't want to clear all the session variables like `reset_session` does.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

```
session.delete(:message)
```

In general, session variable is `SessionHash` object, which is inherited from hash.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. session[:message] = nil will leave the :message key in the session hash, this will destroy the key and value, as if your session never had any value assigned to that key.

Comment: @BrettBender is this still true for rails 6? thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I haven't used ruby / rails in a long time (Rails 4). This comment is over a decade old! :P

Comment: @Crashalot this is still valid for Rails 6 according to the Ruby on Rails Guides (v6.1.4): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session