# Rails session[:user_id] wont destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Im new to Rails and having troubles trying to destroy the user session. 
My session controller looks like this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        name = params[:name]
        password = params[:password]

        user = User.authenticate(name, password)

        if user.nil?
             render json: {isLogin: false}
        else
             session[:user_id] = user.id
             render json: {isLogin: true}
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        puts session[:user_id]  # Nothing gets printed to the console here
        render json: {isLogin: false}
    end 
end
```

When I call 'sessions/destroy' and try to destroy the session, nothing gets printed at 'puts session[:user_id]' line. So I know for sure that the session is nil at that point. But the problem is that I can still access the session like this from a different controller even after I destroy the session for that user.

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController

    def getLesson
        userId = session[:user_id]
        # do stuff
    end

end
```

Why is this happening? and how can I fix this?.

Comment: how do you call the route? how did you define the route? In `getLesson`; what does it print?

Comment: This *might be* a duplicate of [What is the best way to clear a session variable in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995816/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-a-session-variable-in-rails)

Comment: um.. try 'puts nil' on a ruby console, what is printed? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
session.delete(:user_id)
```

instead of

```
session[:user_id] = nil
```

That is what I have had luck with in the past.