# Proper way to remove specific session variables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

I've built a multi page form wizard for a single model in rails, as a user enters data into the form regardless of the wizard page, the data is saved in session parameters. All works great, until the user finally submits the form, then I want those session parameters to also be cleared out.

I currently am removing the session by its attribute name and then resetting the session. This appears to work, but then if the page is refreshed, the original session will return. I have cleared the cache, and cookies but it seems like this is caused by the browser saving the session somewhere that the delete and rest are not catching.

In my controller after the new object is saved I call this to clear the session

```rb
session[:design_attributes] = nil
reset_session
redirect_to :controller => 'designs', :action => 'index'
```

Am I missing something, that also needs to be removed from the client side session? I would expect that the user, after hitting the above code should never be able to refresh their browser and see the session variables repopulated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to clear a session variable in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995816/what-is-the-best-way-to-clear-a-session-variable-in-rails)

Comment: @stealththeninja I don't think so but it's been so long & this setup no longer exists...